# pass list of list into numba function in no python mode, if element in list_of_list[0] doe not work

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba, numba-pro

See the following minimum code,

```
import numba
list_of_list = [[1, 2], [34, 100]]
@numba.njit()
def test(list_of_list):
    if 1 in list_of_list[0]:
        return 'haha'

test(list_of_list)
```

This won't work and it seems that list_of_list[0] is no longer behaves like a list during compile. However, the following code works:

```
list_of_list = [[1, 2], [34, 100]][0] # this is a list NOW!
@numba.njit()
def test(list_of_list):
    if 1 in list_of_list:
        return 'haha'

test(list_of_list)
```

This time, what I pass into is actually list, NOT list of list. Then it works. It seems `for i in list` works in numba, not `for i in list_of_list`.

In my use case, passing list of list or array like 2d data into numba function is common. Sometimes I only need one element in the list, which is dynamically determined in the program.

In order to make it work, I actually worked out a solution: **making `list_of_list` flattened into a `long list`**, then use linear index to extract one element in original `list_of_list`.

I am asking here, is there other alternative solutions?

Comment: Why are you storing array like 2d data in lists of lists instead of a numpy array? Numba can't work directly on lists, they are converted in an internal representation which is quite costly and comes with some limitations (same dtype -> the second example will fail if you put a float inside, no list of lists..) https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html

Comment: stored in numpy array, is the same, `if 1 in array2d[0]` won't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in method works on sets. Returning a string can also cause some problems.

**Working example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

array_2D = np.array([[1, 2], [34, 100]])

@nb.njit()
def test(array_2D):
    if 1 in set(array_2D[0]):
        #Strings also causes sometimes problems
        #return 'haha'
        return(1)
    else:
        return(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a string with my revised version. It passed test and worked successfully.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np


@njit
def test():
    if 1 in set(np_list_of_list[0]):
        return 'haha'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_list = [[1, 2], [34, 100]]
    np_list_of_list = np.array(list_of_list)
    print(test())
```